# i want to display data according to type in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have following table "vehicle_data" :

```
ID    ALERT_TYPE    VALUE
58      2             1
58      1             1
104     1             1
104     2             1
```

Here alert_type = 2 is for  GPS value and alert_type=1 is for engine_value .

```
so if alert_type=2 and its value is =1 then it means its value is correct.
when alert_type=2 and its value is =0 then it means its value is wrong.

same for alert_type=1
```

so now here i want the following output:

```
ID    gps    engine_value  
58     1      1
104    1      1
```

how can i perform this query??

Comment: Can you share your output columns and sample data for output so that we get the query for you, Also please let us what you have tried so far to get the output?

Comment: i have edit my question. please check it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
SELECT ID
   ,CASE WHEN [ALERT_TYPE]=2 and [value ]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gps 
    ,CASE WHEN [ALERT_TYPE]=1 and [value ]=1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as engine

FROM vehicle_data
```

Comment: i have update my table value and out put please check it.Thank you

Comment: GROUP BY [ID] will do it

Comment: [sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63c66/3] check this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, alert_type=2 AS gps, alert_type=1 AS [engine] FROM vehicle_data WHERE value=1;
```

EDITED to account for your explanation of VALUE.

Comment: well, you edited your question after my post. You only want the rows where value=1

Comment: engine is a keyword. try `engine` (escaping the name)

Comment: sorry, I have mysql syntax, not sql server.

Comment: i have update my table value and out put please check it.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

BASED ON YOUR QUESTION I BELIEVE YOU WANT THE DATA IN COLUMN AND TO SUIT YOUR REQUIREMENT I HAVE MADE A SQL FIDDLE WORKING - CODE IS ALSO MENTIONED BELOW -

HERE YOU GO WITH THE WORKING FIDDLE -

[WORKING DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b110d7/2)

SQL CODE FOR REFERNECE -

```
CREATE TABLE ALERTS (ID INT, ALERT_TYPE INT, VALUE INT)

INSERT INTO ALERTS VALUES (58,2,1)
INSERT INTO ALERTS VALUES (58,1,0)
INSERT INTO ALERTS VALUES (104,1,1)
INSERT INTO ALERTS VALUES (104,2,0)

CREATE TABLE ALERTSVALUE (ID INT, gps INT,engine INT)

INSERT INTO ALERTSVALUE VALUES (58,1,0)
INSERT INTO ALERTSVALUE VALUES (104,0,1)



SELECT A.ID, 
CASE A.ALERT_TYPE WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GPS, 
CASE A.ALERT_TYPE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ENGINE_VALUE, 
A.VALUE FROM ALERTS A WHERE A.VALUE = 1
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT** - TO MERGE THE ROWS FOR BOTH GPS AND ENGINE_VALUE:

```
SELECT X.ID,X.ALERT_TYPE as GPS,X.VALUE as ENGINE_VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT ID,ALERT_TYPE ,VALUE ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY alert_type ) AS [Rank] FROM ALERTS
 )X
 WHERE [Rank]=1
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b110d7/4)

Comment: i have update my table value and out put please check it.Thank you

Comment: @deepak - one ID should either have alert_type and value matching once, you sample data will give you records correct for both alert_types therefore you get one record twice. As per the logic it  is correct.

Comment: if your data has the correct values it will contain duplicate values - you will need to rectify the data - there is no identifier to say that for ID 58 gps is correct and engine is incorrect - it says both are correct. So you will have both the records, which means duplicate entry for ID but it is not duplicate records for SQL query

Comment: but i want it in 1 row for both id...i dont want different row for other value

Answer (score 0):

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (id int, ALERT_TYPE int)
INSERT table3 VALUES (58, 1), (58, 2), (104, 1), (104, 2)
```

### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id
            ) AS row_num
        ,gps = CASE 
            WHEN ALERT_TYPE = 2
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ,engine = CASE 
            WHEN ALERT_TYPE = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
    FROM table3
    ) a
WHERE a.row_num = 1
```

### Output

```
ID    gps    engine  
58     1      0
104    0      1
```

Comment: i have update my table value and out put please check it.Thank you

Comment: i have update column value of "vehicle_data" table...have update all value = 1. and also expected output

Comment: Have you tested my query posted in my answer ??

Answer (score 0):

One possible way using subqueries :

```
select 
    Ids.ID
    , gps.VALUE 'gps'
    , engine_value.VALUE 'engine_value'
from (select distinct ID from vehicle_data) Ids
    left join 
        (select ID, VALUE from vehicle_data where ALERT_TYPE = 2) gps 
    on gps.ID = Ids.ID
    left join 
        (select ID, VALUE from vehicle_data where ALERT_TYPE = 1) engine_value 
    on engine_value.ID = Ids.ID
```

**[[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e7974/1)]**

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work for you,

```
Select ID,sum(gps) as gps ,sum(engine) as engine from 
(SELECT ID
   ,CASE WHEN [ALERT_TYPE]=2 and [value ]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gps 
    ,CASE WHEN [ALERT_TYPE]=1 and [value ]=1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as engine

FROM vehicle_data
)a
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select x.id,x.alert_type as GPS,x.value as engine_value   from (
 select ID,alert_type,value,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by alert_type ) as Rnk from mytable
 )x
 where Rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query in SQL :

```
create table mytable (id int, alert_type int, value int);

insert into mytable (id, alert_type, value)
values (58, 2, 1),
(58, 1, 1),
(104, 1, 1),
(104, 2, 1);


SELECT distinct ID
   ,(select count (id) from mytable mt where mt.id=mytable.id and mt.[ALERT_TYPE]=2 and mt.[value ]=1) as gps 
    ,(select count (id) from mytable mt where mt.id=mytable.id and mt.[ALERT_TYPE]=1 and mt.[value ]=1) as engine

FROM mytable
```